# gtkmm/glibmm: dbus application launch

Tags: c++, gtk, dbus, gtkmm

How do I write gtkmm 3 application which can be automatically launched as a service by DBus daemon? I think I'm missing some doc, but I can't find which one.

I want to write Gnome search provider using C++ and gtkmm.

I took a brief look at official "Programming with gtkmm 3", and my HelloWorld-like app works fine.

Then I tried to write simple DBus server, based on example: examples/dbus/session_bus_service.cc - it also works fine. This is actual simplified main():

```
int main(int, char**)
{
  Gio::init();

  introspection_data = Gio::DBus::NodeInfo::create_for_xml(introspection_xml);

  const auto id = Gio::DBus::own_name(...);

  auto loop = Glib::MainLoop::create();
  loop->run();

  Gio::DBus::unown_name(id);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Then I've found HowDoI/SearchProvider on Gnome Wiki. It says,

> Let's assume that we have an application called Foo Bar that is D-Bus
>   activatable, ...

Ok, so I need DBus activable application. Hopefully, there is also a HowDoI. 
Here is TL/DR version of https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/DBusApplicationLaunching:

- You should already be using GtkApplication
- Creating separate service application is not recommended
- Use the standard commandline parsing mechanism. (...) When started with some switch, the application will be in service mode

So, I wrote standard HelloWorld GtkApplication with gtkmm 3:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, g_appName);

  CHelloWorldWindow helloworld;

  return app->run(helloworld);
}
```

And now I got stuck. In order to support DBus Application Launch I'm using GTK::Application. It has its own message loop. But as far as I understand, I need to place DBus initialization and Glib::MainLoop somewhere in application's message look.

I looked at docs, but so far I have no idea about where to write dbus initialization code and how to combine it with GTK::Application loop.